# kibana read only dashboard

Tags: kibana, kibana-5, xpack

I am trying to configure roles to a user to give him access to dashboard but only in read only mode:this "read only" user can see a dashboard but cannot save modifications.

I tried several solutions :

1. x-pack

I tried to install x-pack but I do not understand wih permissions I should give to my "read only" user.

2. Change kibana settings

I tried to change kibana settings :

```
PUT .kibana/_settings
{ "index.blocks.read_only" : false }
```

It works fine but nobody can change the dashboard anymore

3. Embedded dashboard

I could also use embedded dashboards but the user cannot have access to time picker.

Thanks for your help.

Corinne

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the kibana_dashboard_only_user reserved role ? 
All datas for thoses users are in a read only mode, and he can only access to dashboards

Answer (score -1):

> I could also use embedded dashboards but the user cannot have access to time picker.

[This](https://github.com/nreese/kibana-time-plugin) plugin works well with Kibana if you put it on your dashboard whilst embedded you are still able to change times.